# Unit Testing window.location.assign using Karma/Mocha/Sinon/Chai

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, sinon, chai

I am attempting to unit test a function using Karma as my test runner, Mocha as my testing framework, Sinon as my mocking/stubbing/spying library, and Chai as my assertion library. I am using Chromium as my headless browser in my Karma configuration.

I am totally baffled, however, as to why I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: assign
```

...when I run npm test on this:

```
function routeToNewPlace() {  
  const newLoc = "/accountcenter/content/ac.html";
  window.location.assign(newLoc);
}
describe('tests', function() {
  before('blah', function() {
    beforeEach('test1', function() {
          window.onbeforeunload = () => '';
      });
    });
  it('routeToNewPlace should route to new place', function() {
    expectedPathname = "/accountcenter/content/ac.html";
    routeToNewPlace();
    const stub = sinon.stub(window.location, 'assign'); 
    assert.equal(true, stub.withArgs(expectedUrl).calledOnce);
    stub.restore();
  });
});
```

As you can see, I am attempting to assign an empty string to window.location, but this doesn't seem to help.

Here is my karma.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
      frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],
      files: ['jstests/**/*.js'],
      reporters: ['progress'],
      port: 9876,  // karma web server port
      colors: true,
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
      //browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'MyHeadlessChrome'],
      browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
      customLaunchers: {
        MyHeadlessChrome: {
          base: 'ChromeHeadless',
          flags: ['--disable-translate', '--disable-extensions', '--remote-debugging-port=9223']
        }
      },
      autoWatch: false,
      // singleRun: false, // Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
      concurrency: Infinity
    })
  }
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edited to add that I am using Chromium headless browser, and to provide my karma.config.js.

Comment: What about using `spy` instead of `stub` in `const stub = sinon.stub(window.location, 'assign');`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is that `window.location.assign` is a native function that is non-writable and non-configurable. See the discussion of [property descriptors on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description).

See this screenshot and it may help you understand:

[image: Showing property descriptor of window.location.assing]

What this means is that sinon cannot spy on the `assign` function since it cannot overwrite its property descriptor.

The simplest solution is to wrap all calls to `window.location.assign` into one of your own methods, like this:

```
function assignLocation(url) {
  window.location.assign(url);
}
```

And then in your tests, you can do:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(window, 'assignLocation');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: and then somehow test this method works lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    writable: true,
    value: {
        assign: () => {}
    }
});
sinon.spy(window.location, 'assign');
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. I just put Object.defineProperty before           sinon.stub(window.location, "assign") and test passed.

Comment: in 2021, I get: `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: location` when I try this sadly